# disabled: '{readOnly}' what's mean ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-modern

I'm working on a project in `ExtJS` started by my colleagues. I found an item of a fieldset which is like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'radiofield',
    name: 'something',
    value: something,
    label: something,
    checked: something,
    bind: {
        disabled: '{readOnly}'
    }
}
```

What is `disabled: '{readOnly}'` ? According to documentation, `disabled:` should be a boolean, so `disabled: '{readOnly}'` what is supposed to be?

Comment: Check this [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/index.html). `disabled: '{readOnly}'` this will disabled your component based on your readonly value and this `readOnly` values is comes from viewmodel. So please read about extjs documentation and if your are using binding then also read about the same.

Answer (score -1):

**Disabled** and **ReadOnly** tags are very similar but have some noticeable differences. The "**Disabled**" tag is used to ensure the user cannot trigger or alter the field and **Field isn't sent when submit is clicked**. Whereas **readOnly** submits the field on submit. In this case, since **readOnly** is used alongside **disabled**, the functionality remains the same i.e. user can't trigger the field and it is not submitted so it is equivalent to:

```js
disabled: true
```

Comment: But what mean the notation '{...}' ?

Comment: standard notation for variables?

Comment: `{text}` means that it is retrieving the value of `text` from the viewmodel for that view. This viewmodel may be on this view or any parent up the chain and can refer to either a simple data value or a boolean. Recommend reading up on viewmodels in the docs - they're very useful.